# Cambio de formato y valor de la hora despues de mapear JSON a OBJETO

Tags: java, date

Tengo un JSON que recibo al cual a la hora de manejarlo me pasa una cosa curiosa.

El JSON es el siguiente :

```
{"id":"10","createdAt":"2019-08-20T06:58:27.848Z","data":""}
```

Ese JSON entrante lo convierto en un objeto usando el ObjectMapper

```
final Bean bean = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Bean.class);
bean.getCreatedAt(); //Tue Aug 20 08:58:27 CEST 2019
```

Mi duda es:

1. Se que la fecha que recibo en el JSON no sale la marca con la zona horaria, pero ¿Por que me coge la hora de mi equipo y me añade las dos horas de la zona horaria de España?
2. Si lograse la hora sin la alteración de la zona horaria (Tue Aug 20 06:58:27 CEST 2019) ¿Como podría formatear la hora a formato original que me llego el JSON (2019-08-20T06:58:27.848Z)?

Comment: La Z final indica una zona horaria +0

Comment: Comprendido gracias

Comment: Aunque revisando me dado cuenta que ahora a la hora de hacer el parseo de formato. Lo que me referia a la segunda pregunta. Me deja la fecha formateada en el formato que queria pero claro ahora me pone una Z al final pero con siendo las 8 en vez de las 6. RESULTADO: 2019-08-20T08:58:27.848Z

Comment: @PabloLozano Claro esto pasa por que formateo la fecha de lo obtenido una vez echa la conversion de JSON a Objeto. Como Tendria que manejar eso. Ya que ahora tengo una alteracion de dos horas debido a a los parseos

Comment: Dependiendo de la clase que estés usando (java.util.Date? java.time.Instant?) existen distintas formas, por ejemplo [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string).

Comment: El ejemplo lo realiza con instant y yo en cambio con date. Sabes de algún post publicado que trate esto?

Comment: Hay muchos, yo lo he evitado porque java.util.Date debería evitar usarse. Mira la clase `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: En otro post me comentaste que no se debería usar. Algún motivo en especial?

Comment: Mira los constructores y métodos marcados como **Deprecated** en el [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)